# C++ Input part of a text file into an array

Tags: c++, file-io, string-parsing

I need to read a txt file of configuration settings organized by heading, such as Menu: , Tables: , Waiter: etc.

One the correct section is found  I need to pull in the correct information. So basically I am trying to search a text file for a specific string and once that string has been found start storing input from lines that occur after the line that contains that string.

What I am trying so far.

```
void MenuItemArray()
{
    string arrayIn;

    ifstream fin("/usr/local/final_project/restaurant/config.txt");

    while (getline(fin, arrayIn))
    {
        if (arrayIn.find("Menu:") == true)
        {
        }
```

The text file I am pulling from:

```
Tables:  table #, max seats
1 2
2 4 
3 2 
4 2 
5 2 
6 4 
7 6 
8 10 
9 2 
10 4 
11 4 
12 4 
13 4 
14 2 
15 2 
16 2 
17 2 
18 2

Waiters:  first name followed by table list
John 1,2,5,9,11,15
Maria 3,4,6,7,17,18
Mike 8,10,12,13,14,16 

Menu: listing of the full menu: item code, name, price
A1 Bruschetta 5.29
A2 Caprese_Flatbread 6.10
A3 Artichoke-Spinach_Dip 3.99
A4 Lasagna_Fritta 4.99
A5 Mozzarella_Fonduta 5.99
E1 Lasagna_Classico 6.99
E2 Capellini_Pomodoro 7.99
E3 Eggplant_Parmigiana 8.99
E4 Fettuccine_Alfredo 7.49
E5 Tour_of_Italy 14.99
D1 Tiramisu 2.99
D2 Zeppoli 2.49
D3 Dolcini 3.49
S1 Soda 1.99
S2 Bella_Limonata 0.99
S3 Berry_Acqua_Fresca 2.88
```

Comment: Start by reading the manual of `std::string::find`; the function doesn't work the way you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is relatively small, you can read all of it into a std::string and then use the std:string find functions.

```
ifstream in("config.txt");
ostringstream oss;
oss << in.rdbuf();
string contents = oss.str();
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work? I tried replicating the problem by using `stringstream` instead of `ifstream` but the contents of the string is empty when I print to standard output.

Comment: Yes, it works with istringstream too, replace ifstream with istringstream and contents has "config.txt" in it.